# Why do I get attribution error in fast-api? AttributeError: type object has no attribute

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using **fast-api** and **pydantic** for modeling in my project, I created a function convert the attributes to dictionary.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class WidgetItem(BaseModel):
    """Class for WidgetItem"""
    adId: str = ''

    @classmethod
    def generate_widget_item_dict(cls):
        return {
            'adId': cls.adId
        }
```

Im trying to call ***generate_widget_item_dict()*** but I got this error:

**AttributeError: type object 'WidgetItem' has no attribute 'adId'**

Comment: You don't want your dict generation method to be a classmethod; it needs to access the value of the instance, not the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where you want only some of the attributes of a given class, I would create multiple classes and return the correctly "masked" class. Here's an example to illustrate:

***Note:** This can get tricky when you have lots of dependencies.*

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class WidgetItem1(BaseModel):
    """
    Class for WidgetItem

    Note: this class only has 1 attribute
    """
    attr_1: str = 'one'


class WidgetItem2(WidgetItem1):
    """
    A more granular class for WidgetItem ->
    Inherited from `WidgetItem1`

    Note: this class has 3 attributes
    """
    attr_2: str = 'two'
    attr_3: str = 'three'
```

Given a fastapi endpoint, you can choose to return
specific attributes, depending on your `response_model`:

- `WidgetItem1`: will return only `attr_1`
- `WidgetItem2`: will return 3 attributes: `attr_1`, `attr_2`, `attr_3`
  Here's some code to demonstrate:

```py
# Choose the response model you want to return

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


# Create a function to use for multiple endpoints
def get_widget():
    """
    Returns a dummy widget to demonstrate
    functionality. Change the `response_model` to
    see different attributes returned.
    """
    # Initially set all 3 attributes and see
    # which are returned by fastapi based on `response_model`
    result = {
        "attr_1": "one",
        "attr_2": "two",
        "attr_3": "three"
    }
    return result


@app.get("/widgets-1", response_model=WidgetItem1)
def get_widget_1():
    """
    Endpoint which wraps `get_widget()` 
    with `WidgetItem1` as the response model
    """
    return get_widget()

@app.get("/widgets-2", response_model=WidgetItem2)
def get_widget_2():
    """
    Endpoint which wraps `get_widget()` 
    with `WidgetItem2` as the response model
    """
    return get_widget()
```

---

Alternatively, you can go ahead and create custom functionality to return a specifically formatted dictionary. If this is the case, the other answers should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

It happens since `WidgetItem` should be initiated since it inherits from `BaseModel`.

This is different than for instance:

```
class WidgetModel:
    adId: str = ""

    @classmethod
    def generate_widget_item_dict(cls):
        return {
            'adId': cls.adId
        }
```

In such a case it will work. However this is not a Pydantic model.

If you want to create a dict from a Pydantic model you can just do:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class WidgetItem(BaseModel):
    """Class for WidgetItem"""
    adId: str


w = WidgetItem(adId="id")
w.dict()
```

Comment: The idea is that I want to create the key different than the attribute name

Comment: @MohamedHaydar Have you considered using the built-in alias support and `dict(by_alias=True)`?

Comment: what id I need some fields from the object not all the attributes? @MatsLindh

Comment: Then you usually create a base pydantic class with those attributes, then inherit that class to add the extra attributes - and in FastAPI use `response_model` with the base model instead of the extended model - and it will automagically return the fields you want.

Comment: Add these clarifying comments into your Q @MohamedHaydar